# Buscar elementos coincidentes de array multidimensional, y eliminar filas Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, function, array-bidimensional

Tengo un array de dos dimensiones con datos de una tabla. Estoy tratando de iterar sobre las filas del mismo, buscando elementos que coincidan en función del valor de una celda (código producto, celda 2). Si un elemento está presente en varias filas, suma el valor de una celda (14) del mismo (inventario) y borraría la fila repetida, quedando así un array con las filas que no se repiten intactas, pero las filas repetidas agrupadas en una, con el valor sumado para cada una. Es decir, si producto1 (stock 7uds) se repite en las filas 5 (3 uds) y 12 (6 uds), el array final debería tener (aparte de las filas de productos que no se repitan) una única fila de producto1 con su celda de stock con 16 uds.

Hasta ahora mi planteamiento ha sido de comprobar cada fila con las siguientes una por una (exceptuando la primera, que tiene los títulos de la tabla) y usar un booleano para marcar si se ha sumado el inventario, de cara a luego borrar las filas repetidas, pero me ha sido imposible hasta ahora borrar las filas, ni usando splice, ni probando otras maneras. ¿Me podría ayudar alguien?

Este es el código de la función hasta ahora:

```
  sumastock = 0; // Donde se guardará cada suma de stock coincidente
  stocktxt = ''; // Para convertir las sumas de stock en String

  stocksumado = new Array(todastiendas.length).fill(false);

  for (var row in todastiendas){
    if (row > 0) {
      for (var row2 in todastiendas) {
        if (row2 > row){
          if (todastiendas[row][2] == todastiendas[row2][2]) {
            if (stocksumado[row] == false){
              sumastock = Number(todastiendas[row][14]) + Number(todastiendas[row2][14]); // suma celdas de stock
              stocktxt = sumastock.toString();
              todastiendas[row][14] = stocktxt;
              stocktxt = '';
              stocksumado[row] = true;
            } else {
              sumastock = Number(todastiendas[row][14]) + Number(todastiendas[row2][14]);
              stocktxt = sumastock.toString();
              todastiendas[row][14] = stocktxt;
              stocktxt = '';
            }
            

            // He probado cosas pero no consigo que todastiendas solo conserve filas únicas sin repetir más las repetidas agrupadas con el stock sumado (esto iría antes del código anterior) 
            /*function borrarFila(arr, fila) {
              arr = arr.slice(0); // hace copia
              arr.splice(fila - 1, 1);
              // console.table(arr);
              return arr;
            }*/
            // borrarFila(todastiendas, row2);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Edit: Adjunto imagen de una parte de la estructura del array
[image: array todastiendas]

Edit2: Contenido del array de prueba

```
[
  ["ID", "Tipo", "SKU", "Nombre", "Publicado", "¿Está destacado?", "Visibilidad en el catálogo", "Descripción corta", "Descripción", "Día en que empieza el precio rebajado", "Día en que termina el precio rebajado", "Estado del impuesto", "Clase de impuesto", "¿En inventario?", "Inventario", "Cantidad de bajo inventario", "¿Permitir reservas de productos agotados?", "¿Vendido individualmente?", "Peso (kg)", "Longitud (cm)", "Anchura (cm)", "Altura (cm)", "¿Permitir valoraciones de clientes?", "Nota de compra", "Precio rebajado", "Precio normal", "Categorías", "Etiquetas", "Clase de envío", "Imágenes", "Límite de descargas", "Días de caducidad de la descarga", "Superior", "Productos agrupados", "Ventas dirigidas", "Ventas cruzadas", "URL externa", "Texto del botón", "Posición", "Minimum Quantity", "Maximum Quantity", "Nombre del atributo 1", "Valor(es) del atributo 1", "Atributo visible 1", "Atributo global 1", "Meta: classic-editor-remember", "Meta: _booking_min", "Meta: _booking_max", "Meta: _number_of_dates", "Meta: _booking_duration", "Meta: _first_available_date", "Meta: _bookable", "Meta: min_quantity", "Meta: max_quantity", "Meta: rs_page_bg_color", "Meta: eg_sources_html5_mp4", "Meta: eg_sources_youtube", "Meta: eg_sources_vimeo", "Meta: eg_sources_wistia", "Meta: eg_sources_image", "Meta: eg_sources_iframe", "Meta: eg_sources_soundcloud", "Meta: eg_vimeo_ratio", "Meta: eg_youtube_ratio", "Meta: eg_wistia_ratio", "Meta: eg_html5_ratio", "Meta: eg_soundcloud_ratio", "Meta: eg_sources_revslider", "Meta: eg_sources_essgrid", "Meta: eg_featured_grid", "Meta: eg_settings_custom_meta_skin", "Meta: eg_settings_custom_meta_element", "Meta: eg_settings_custom_meta_setting", "Meta: eg_settings_custom_meta_style", "Meta: eg_custom_meta_216", "Meta: eg_votes_count", "Meta: _yoast_wpseo_focuskw", "Meta: _yoast_wpseo_title", "Meta: _yoast_wpseo_metadesc", "Meta: _yoast_wpseo_linkdex", "Meta: _yoast_wpseo_content_score", "Meta: _yoast_wpseo_estimated-reading-time-minutes", "Meta: min_quantity_var", "Meta: max_quantity_var", "Meta: _likes", "Meta: _yoast_wpseo_primary_product_cat"],
  ["", "simple", "10023661998M", "100% MASCARA MOTO BUBBLE GUM", "0", "0", "hidden", "", "", "", "", "taxable", "", "1", "1", "", "0", "0", "", "", "", "", "0", "", "", "29,52", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "0", "", "", "", "", "", "", "classic-editor", "", "", "global", "", "", "no", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "true", "0", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
  ["", "simple", "10041368154S", "100% Máscaras Accuri 2 Goggle Tarmac - True Gold Lens", "0", "0", "hidden", "", "", "", "", "taxable", "", "1", "2", "", "0", "0", "", "", "", "", "0", "", "", "68,9", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "0", "", "", "", "", "", "", "classic-editor", "", "", "global", "", "", "no", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "true", "0", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
  ["", "simple", "10043792944S", "100% Máscaras Accuri 2 Goggle Tokyo - Mirror Green Lens", "0", "0", "hidden", "", "", "", "", "taxable", "", "1", "2", "", "0", "0", "", "", "", "", "0", "", "", "68,9", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "0", "", "", "", "", "", "", "classic-editor", "", "", "global", "", "", "no", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "true", "0", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
  ["", "simple", "22633526656E", "226Ers Energy Drink 50G Lemon - Monodose", "0", "0", "hidden", "", "", "", "", "taxable", "", "1", "20", "", "0", "0", "", "", "", "", "0", "", "", "2,6", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "0", "", "", "", "", "", "", "classic-editor", "", "", "global", "", "", "no", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "true", "0", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
  ["", "simple", "SPI3540159L", "Spiuk Maillot M/L Top Ten Hombre Negro T. Xxl", "0", "0", "hidden", "", "", "", "", "taxable", "", "1", "2", "", "0", "0", "", "", "", "", "0", "", "", "89,9", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "0", "", "", "", "", "", "", "classic-editor", "", "", "global", "", "", "no", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "true", "0", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
  ["", "simple", "22639746238A", "226Ers Energy Gel Bio 25Gr 100Mg Caffeine Cola*", "0", "0", "hidden", "", "", "", "", "taxable", "", "1", "7", "", "0", "0", "", "", "", "", "0", "", "", "2", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "0", "", "", "", "", "", "", "classic-editor", "", "", "global", "", "", "no", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "true", "0", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
  ["", "simple", "22626748695L", "226Ers Face Mask Movistar Ear - L", "0", "0", "hidden", "", "", "", "", "taxable", "", "1", "3", "", "0", "0", "", "", "", "", "0", "", "", "15", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "0", "", "", "", "", "", "", "classic-editor", "", "", "global", "", "", "no", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "true", "0", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
  ["", "simple", "22633526656E", "226Ers Energy Drink 50G Lemon - Monodose", "0", "0", "hidden", "", "", "", "", "taxable", "", "1", "20", "", "0", "0", "", "", "", "", "0", "", "", "2,6", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "0", "", "", "", "", "", "", "classic-editor", "", "", "global", "", "", "no", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "true", "0", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
  ["", "simple", "10035768155E", "100% RACECRAFT KIKASS LENTE TRANSPARENTE", "0", "0", "hidden", "", "", "", "", "taxable", "", "1", "2", "", "0", "0", "", "", "", "", "0", "", "", "75", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "0", "", "", "", "", "", "", "classic-editor", "", "", "global", "", "", "no", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "true", "0", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""],
  ["", "simple", "10043792944S", "100% Máscaras Accuri 2 Goggle Tokyo - Mirror Green Lens", "0", "0", "hidden", "", "", "", "", "taxable", "", "1", "1", "", "0", "0", "", "", "", "", "0", "", "", "68,9", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "0", "", "", "", "", "", "", "classic-editor", "", "", "global", "", "", "no", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "true", "0", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", ""]
]
```

Comment: SI el booleano y el else sobra ahora mismo no le doy demasiada importancia, ya que los dejé ahí por planteamiento inicial, aunque luego no le esté dando uso por ahora. Lo que no consigo es formatear la tabla de contenido en función de las comparaciones y sumas.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien lo que quieres hacer. Para eliminar una propiedad de un objeto puedes usar `delete objeto.propiedad`. En cambio si solo quieres quedarte con los elementos en los que se haya modificado el stock puedes hacer un `array.filter()`

Comment: Gracias por tu contestación. Quiero comprobar que cada producto de cada fila no esté repetido dentro del mismo array, y si lo está, sumar su stock.

Si tengo FilaProducto1 con 3 uds, FilaProducto2 con 5 uds, FilaProducto3 con 4 uds y FilaProducto1 otra vez con 11 uds, conseguir que el array tenga FilaProducto1 con 14uds, FilaProducto2 5 uds, FilaProducto3 4 uds.

Comprueba la celda 2 de cada fila del mismo array (la celda que tiene el código de producto) y si se repite, suma la celda 14 de ese producto (la celda que tiene el stock). Pero no consigo borrar la fila repetida luego.

Comment: Para eliminar una fila solo pon `todastiendas.splice(row2, 1)`

Comment: Gracias Federico pero ya lo he probado con anterioridad y, quizá por algún error mío, no consigo hacer bien la suma y filtrado/borrado

Comment: Haz un `console.log(JSON.stringify(todastiendas))` y pega el resultado aquí.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo crearía un array vacío y iría añadiendo los elementos. Si existe en lugar de añadir modificaría el stock y si no existe, añado un nuevo elemento al array.

```javascript
let elementosSumados = [];
for (var row in todastiendas) {
  if (row > 0) {
    const existeElemento = elementosSumados.find(x => x[2] === todastiendas[row][2]);
    if (existeElemento) {
      elementosSumados = elementosSumados.map(elem => {
        if (elem[2] === todastiendas[row][2]) {
          elem[14] = Number(elem[14]) + Number(todastiendas[row][14]);
        }
        return elem;
      });
    } else {
      elementosSumados.push(todastiendas[row]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ya está arreglada. Perdona por los errores, pero es que no tenía el editor a mano y lo hice al vuelo en la página :)

Comment: @Suso muchas gracias :) Lo único que debería añadir ahora es inicializar el array de elementos sumados con la primera fila de títulos de columna y convertir en String el stock sumado, pero tu planteamiento y su lógica y sintaxis funcionan perfectamente :) Muy agradecido